# A small signal NMOS transistor

Tags: mosfet, analog, switching

I am reading an application note entitled [Using MOSFETs in Load Switch Applications](http://www.onsemi.com/pub_link/Collateral/AND9093-D.PDF)

This part says that Q1 is a small signal NMOS transistor. Could you explain what does it mean by "small signal transistor" here?
I am familiar with small signal but it is strange to talk about it in switching application.

[image]

Comment: How much power does Q1 have to handle?

Answer (score 2):

It is simply a transistor that doesn't fit under the "power" or "RF" transistor designations, e.g. a 2N7000.